# Update to Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 3.0 does not group by tag anymore

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle, swagger-codegen

I was using `[SwaggerOperation(Tags = new[] { "GroupA" })]` to group my actions within a controller in Swagger UI.

After updating to 3.0 this is not taken into account anymore and is only grouped by controller name.

The "changed" tag names from the attribute are also not generated into the Swagger JSON/YAML anymore, there is just the controller name as a tag.

I was not able to find a hint in the [release notes](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/releases/tag/v3.0.0) regarding breaking changes of this behavior.

Any insights about behavioral changes and/or how I could restore it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are comments on the release notes about this... you will be better off reporting a bug directly on the github page for that project: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/new

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, it is well documented, just a little hard to find... or I should just wait for another 2 cups of coffee when doing this kind of stuff. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So all of this is well documented in the release notes, you just shouldn't be in a rush while reading it.

What I did not mention in my question was that I needed to install `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations` to get `[SwaggerOperation]` back (it has been separated).

And these now need to be actively enabled via:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
   ...

   c.EnableAnnotations();
});
```

From the release notes:

> Updates to annotations: To continue using the swagger-specific
>   annotations, you'll need to explicitly install and enable the new
>   Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations package as described here.

"here" brings you exactly to the place where this step is described:

https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#swashbuckleaspnetcoreannotations

Comment: Just had the exact same problem, good to see I wasn't the only one who missed this in the docs!

Comment: Great thanks. Ported an API to .net 8.0 from 4.8. Not feasible to read all the docs of everything involved. This solution worked great thanks